# Why my program is not called in the script?

Tags: linux

I make a program (a daemon), and put it in a script which will be called when boot up. The script is like below. By this way, my program is not called at all. Because I checked `ps | grep myprogram`. And please notice that script  `read_something.sh` does not exist!

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe some_driver
dmesg | grep BIOS > /bioslog

setsid /usr/bin/myprogram &
read_something.sh
```

But I exchange the sequence of the last items, then myprogram is called and runs at a daemon well.

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe some_driver
dmesg | grep BIOS > /bioslog

read_something.sh
setsid /usr/bin/myprogram &
```

Why?

**More:**
My script is called automatically via systemd service.
The case my program `monitor` can be loaded.

```
root@tomxue--------:~# ps | grep monitor
  480 root     36288 S    /usr/bin/monitor
  984 root      7796 S    grep monitor
root@tomxue--------:~# cat /usr/bin/speaker_autoexe.sh 
#!/bin/bash

exec 2>/home/root/123.log; set -x

read_sn.sh
setsid /usr/bin/monitor &
root@tomxue--------:~# cat 123.log 
+ read_sn.sh
/usr/bin/speaker_autoexe.sh: line 5: read_sn.sh: command not found
+ setsid /usr/bin/monitor
```

The case my program monitor can not be loaded.

```
root@tomxue--------:~# ps | grep monitor
  769 root      7796 R    grep monitor
root@tomxue--------:~# cat /usr/bin/speaker_autoexe.sh 
#!/bin/bash

exec 2>/home/root/123.log; set -x

setsid /usr/bin/monitor &
read_sn.sh
root@tomxue--------:~# cat 123.log 
+ read_sn.sh
+ setsid /usr/bin/monitor
/usr/bin/speaker_autoexe.sh: line 6: read_sn.sh: command not found
```

Comment: At the top of your script (well, after the shebang), add this line: `exec 2>/path/to/your.log; set -x` -- then amend your question to include that log.

Comment: ...in general, though, this is Doing It Wrong -- the right way to run a program in the background that starts on boot is to use your operating system's process supervision system, be that systemd or upstart or launchd or daemontools; these will ensure that output is logged, and that it restarts on failure.

Comment: Use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) near start of your script and look in your system logs if you script has started.

Comment: How can you tell that your _program is not called at all_ by checking `ps`? Your program could have been called and already terminated due to some error condition, couldn't it?